# how to get the non existing record in a table using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'table1' and it has some records like below.

[image]

Now i have written the query like below,

```
select value, name 
from table1 
where value in ('1a2b3c','8s9r3h','5h2j0m','4m5m6n','8i9o7l');
```

In the above query returns the records which are available in the table. But i have to return the data for the non existing records `('4m5m6n','8i9o7l')` well.
The final output should look like below,

[image]

Kindly let me know is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT value, table1.name 
FROM (
    VALUES
    ROW('1a2b3c'), ROW('8s9r3h'), ROW('5h2j0m'), ROW('4m5m6n'), ROW('8i9o7l')
    ) all_values (value)
LEFT JOIN table1 USING (value);
```

Comment: Getting syntax error

Comment: @RavichandranJothi WHAT error? Maybe your MySQL version is too old? if so then use common `SELECT .. UNION ALL ..` instead of row constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating a dataset with `union all` and then joining it using `left join` to your table:

```
select s.value, t.name
from (
  select '1a2b3c' as value
  union all
  select '8s9r3h'
  union all
  select '5h2j0m'
  union all
  select '4m5m6n'
  union all
  select '8i9o7l'
) as s
left join mytable t on s.value = t.value
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qU-H1yL7)